# HP Wifi button and wifi not working

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I am using hp laptop and recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I was previously using windows and wifi button was working fine in that so I think Wifi button is okay but in ubuntu it is always orange (switched off).

I searched on askubuntu and tried

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

but it didn't work and also I don't see any output once I use this command

My iwconfig output is

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I also tried rebooting system after setting the bios to default but that also didn't work for me. I also tried removing battery method but that also didn't work.

Hopefully someone has answer to this problem.

Comment: Please edit to add results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: This can be closed now, I fixed it.
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796